# Create a UIViewController from UITabbarItem and Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to open a UIViewController if I press the second UITabbarItem.

Here is my code of the first ViewController. It sets the Label.text, if I press UITabbarItem #1 (Tag 1). At #2 I want to switch to the secondViewController and (Tag 2) it crashes.
Anyone knows why? First Breakpoint is at UIStoryboard... (Storyboard is called: Main.storyboard). Thanks for help

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tabBar.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
    switch (item.tag) {
        case 1:        self.testlabel.text =@"test";
            break;
        case 2:
        {  // create the Storyboard object
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        secondViewController *second = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondview"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
        }         
        break;
        default:         break; }
}
@end
```

[image: Error]

Comment: I guess it works now, but is there a way to do this without having a navigation controller?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things.

1. if not already make a property for the `UITabBarController`
2. Unless you want to navigate away from the `UITabBarController` you do not push the view controller, you would have to either manually set the view controller to the tabBar item or re-set the view controllers array with in the tabBarController.

   NSMutableArray* newControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];

   [newControllers addObject:second];

   [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:newControllers animated:NO];
3. Your `UITabBarController` is in a storyboard? hold the right click button over the tab you want and drag it over the controller, then set that controller as the location for the tab, if you do that you can ignore 1 and 2 above
4. `UITabBarController` are not meant to do different functionality per tab, so that's a bad coding practice to have the first tab set a label and the second tab display an `UIViewController`, but that is irrelevant.

After all of that `UITabBarController` stuff, the app is possibly crashing because your `UINavigationController` is nil, or you get a **"SecondView is not value coding compliant error"** or something similiar, this means that a property is set in a storyboard to an item that no longer exist. So with in the storyboard right click the the view controller and see if you see any yellow warning markers, if so hit the "X" next to them all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort. I am not using UITabBarController. Just UITabBar with 2 x UITabbarItem. I am trying to do this without UITabBarcontroller from Storyboard, because I want to have custom tabBars in each ViewController later. Is this possible with UITabbarcontroller?

Comment: oh, i see what you are doing, yes it is possible, if you would want to have custom tab bars per controller then you are on the right track, do you have the logs of the error? that would help me to understand your set up C:

Comment: [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; is that the name of your storyboard or should it be [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];